# How do i use hidden *this pointer?

Tags: c++, this, method-chaining

I have this code:

```cpp
class Something
{
private:
    int m_value = 0;
public:
    Something add(int value)
    {
        m_value += value;
        return *this;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
        return m_value;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Something a;
    Something b = a.add(5).add(5);
    cout << a.getValue() << endl;
    cout << b.getValue() << endl;
}
```

output:

```
5
10
```

I wanted `add()` to return the `a` object, so that the second `add()` is  like `(*this).add(5)`, but this doesn't work. However, `b` is good (how?). I expected `a` to be 10, the same as `b`.

So, where did I miss the usage of hidden pointer? What should I do so that `a.add(5).add(5)` changes the `m_value` of `a` to be 10?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What output did you expect?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: `add` returns *a copy* of `Something` instance. Your next call in chain modifies that temporary copy. Did you want to return `Something&` from `add`?

Comment: The `Something&` comment is a reasonable guess, but it's unfortunate that we are guessing.  Doesn't your code add `5` to `a`?  Doesn't `b` get assigned that value with another `5` added to it?  Your output is correct, and you have not explained what "doesn't work".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add()` is returning `*this` **by value**, so it is returning a *copy* of `*this`, so the chained `add()` is modifying the copy, not the original.

`add()` needs to return `*this` **by reference** instead:

```
Something& add(int value)
{
    m_value += value;
    return *this;
}
```

**UPDATE:** `a` initially has `m_value` set to 0, then `a.add(5)` sets `a.m_value` to 5 and then returns a *copy* of `a`. Then `<copy>.add(5)` sets `<copy>.m_value` to 10 and returns another *copy*, which is then assigned to `b`. That is why you see `a` is 5 but `b` is 10.